# Cannot find module 'npmlog' error message when using npm command

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, npm

Today is my first day of my first job and after setting up my development environment by updating node and npm on my Mac (OSX) I seem to have broken something. Every time I try to use npm in my commandline (npm init, npm install, etc.) I get this error message:

> module.js:339
>
> throw err;
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
>
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
>
> at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
>
> at require (module.js:385:17)
>
> at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:20:13
>
> at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm->cli.js:76:3)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)

There isn't much of an error message to go off and the stack trace isn't helping me all that much either. Here's what I have tried:

1. Searched around Stackoverflow and though there are similar problems, people have been able to use `npm <something>` to solve their problem, which I cannot do.
2. Uninstalling and reinstalling npm - Didn't work because I can't use npm command at all so things like `sudo npm uninstall npm -g` don't work.
3. Removed `npmlog` directory from `.npm` directory and then cloned the github repo directly to the directory again.

Hopefully one of you have run into this before or have an idea of how to approach it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

Here is one good link [`Fixing npm On Mac OS X for Homebrew Users`](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689).

with following commands when try to upgrade `node.js` under mac

> ```
> rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
> brew uninstall node
> brew install node --without-npm
> echo prefix=~/.npm-packages >> ~/.npmrc
> curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the link. It saved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: On OS X El Capitan while installing npm 3.9.3, I had a `npm: command not found` after doing this. I had do add `export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"` to my `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 17):

Here are the steps that worked for me:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
$ brew uninstall node
$ brew install node
```

Answer (score 11):

Try `curl -0 -L http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh` to follow redirects. Also notice I added sudo before the sudo sh command depending on your users permissions.

Answer (score 5):

I've just encountered this issue on a Mac, and on closer inspection it seems to me that the problem is that inside the Node application directory in certain circumstances the link in the `node/bin` directory to `npm` in `lib/node_modules/npm/bin` is replaced by the file itself and that is why it fails (and why all the various script methods fix it, because they correctly retain the file link).

If I copy the contents from `node-v6.9.4-darwin-x64` with `cp` then I get this problem, but if I copy the files using the Finder, then I don't. So, you can fix it by manually recreating the link with `ln` if you don't want to use the Finder (alternatively, `mv` or `rsync -a` could work too; I haven't tested them).

Hope this helps someone coming here for this problem.

Edit: I've just accidentally found the reason for the problem on Macs (for my particular scenario, at any rate): I've always used `cp -r` to copy directories. This is because I am old, and don't learn new things any more. The correct way is `cp -R`, which correctly copies everything, as it should.

Comment: Thanks, I had the exact same issue. I downloaded a pre-built package from nodejs.org, extracted it on my mac, then uploaded it to my target system via SFTP. Once on the target system, the symlink was broken, resulting in the above error message. Removing the broken link: node/bin/npm and replacing it with `ln -s node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js node/bin/npm` has fixed the issue.

Comment: I should have mentioned that using `ln -nfs` should remove the original file and replace it with the soft link. Saves you a step! Although it can sometimes fail.

Comment: I used scp to copy from one server to another and experienced this same issue.

Comment: This answer gave me the solution when downloading the macOS binaries straight from the website, although it took a while to get to the root of it: use `cp -R` instead of `cp -r`

Answer (score 3):

I didn't necessarily "fix" the problem as much as just start over. I used this post to do so: [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

If anyone else knows how to actually fix the problem or knows what I did to cause it I would still be very interested.

Answer (score 3):

in my condition, I just 
    `brew uninstall node`
and download from the official site and worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I hit this on Fedora 27 after I ran `sudo npm install npm -g`.

The problem was that I had initially installed Node.js via `sudo dnf install nodejs` which installs npm into `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib`. However running `sudo npm install` installs a separate version in `/usr/bin/`

Running `which npm` shows up that the extra npm is installed. Then the following cleaned everything for me:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/npm
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
$ dnf remove -y nodejs
$ dnf install -y nodejs
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved me some time since I have your same setup. The error comes back every time I try to update via npm though

Comment: Yeah - I think you just can't - if you're using `dnf` then you have to wait until there's a new version of `npm` via `dnf`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error. This was on a server not connected to the internet. I had seen a thread on Github that mentioned sometimes symbolic links can be removed while performing copies or other file operations. So I did a "find" on the node directory for symbolic links of the problematic server and none where found. Doing the same on a working server found symbolic link files.

I went to **NODE_HOME/bin** and did an **ls -l**

Sure enough I had a file for npm. Performed the same steps on a working server and the npm file was a symbolic link. To fix the problematic server, I performed the following:

**rm npm**

**ln -s ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js npm**

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error while installing protractor in REDHAT linux updated the

> npm

file at

> /node-v6.10.2-linux-x64/bin/npm

for the module path as below:

Code Before

```
var log = require('npmlog')
```

Code After

```
var log = require('/node-v6.10.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog')
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I ran `brew uninstall node` and then download the latest version from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/) and it worked.